# Paperclip finding an image using send

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have no problem finding an image path using this query:

```
>> Branch.first.image1.url(:large)
=> "branch.png"
```

However, when doing the very same thing using .send, I have an issue:

```
>> Branch.first.send("image#{1}.url(:large)")
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `image1.url(:large)' for #<Branch:0x00000013b46ac8>>
```

Any idea how to get around this, and still use the send method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each method needs to be called seperately:

```
Branch.first.send("image#{1}").url(:large)
```

Comment: Thanks... thought I'd tried that, but I obviously missed it! It works.